# Integers to two bytes in binary files

Tags: r

I want to write some integers to a binary file and I want to force them to be written in two bytes even if a few of them don't fit (trim these). I get an error when I do this (below). Is there another way to do it? Thanks!

Error in writeBin(Info_Differences, file_differences, size = 2) : 
  size 2 is unknown on this machine

Comment: Related: [Writing small integers to binary files in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016122/writing-small-integers-to-binary-files-in-r)

Comment: Make sure they are integers. Check with is.integer/numeric. If any of them is numeric then size = 2 is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you probably have doubles that **look** like integers. Try this:

```
writeBin(as.integer(Info_Differences), file_differences, size = 2)
```

or, to check what Info_Differences really is:

```
typeof(Info_Differences) # double or integer?
```